# Separate frontend- REST API architecture

Tags: reactjs, rest, deployment, architecture, nuxt.js

I dockerized my api backend (nginx as reverse proxy, express, and mongodb) and now I want to connect it with my frontend platform using Nuxt.js (actually, it could be anything).
Because I don't want to be overwhelmed by CORS policy, I want to put it on the same origin.

What is the best way to deploy it?
Is it by also dockerizing the platform (nuxtjs)?
Or, should I use `pm2` to run the platform on port 3000 and configure the nginx on my dockerized api to proxy_pass everything to localhost:3000 ?

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use nginx to proxy your frontend as well as your API.  Then they can all have the same origin.